# What does the YOLOv4 training output mean?

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolo

In the first line the number 5043 means an interaction that I am in, right? Without the end line of the same line, the time remaining to complete the training (~ 47 hours).

I would like to know what other lines mean, especially the last one

```
 5043: 0.668292, 1.235671 avg loss, 0.001000 rate, 20.289504 seconds, 322752 images, 47.346673 hours left
Loaded: 14.566142 seconds - performance bottleneck on CPU or Disk HDD/SSD
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, cls: 1.00) Region 139 Avg (IOU: 0.000000, GIOU: 0.000000), Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.000000, No Obj: 0.000004, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000, count: 1, class_loss = 0.000049, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.000049 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, cls: 1.00) Region 150 Avg (IOU: 0.812168, GIOU: 0.808716), Class: 0.938050, Obj: 0.072795, No Obj: 0.000732, .5R: 1.000000, .75R: 0.800000, count: 10, class_loss = 2.413296, iou_loss = 3.502501, total_loss = 5.915797 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, cls: 1.00) Region 161 Avg (IOU: 0.781551, GIOU: 0.775137), Class: 0.985000, Obj: 0.347750, No Obj: 0.016977, .5R: 1.000000, .75R: 0.694444, count: 36, class_loss = 6.508103, iou_loss = 1.942730, total_loss = 8.450833 
 total_bbox = 17899, rewritten_bbox = 0.050282 %
```

Comment: here you can find some detail https://timebutt.github.io/static/understanding-yolov2-training-output/

Comment: Check this out https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/darknet_faq/ .  
Regarding the Loading time bottleneck, you might be training on images of one size while the network is configured for other size. this bottlenecks the CPU on resize.